# Tunneling application for linux

Tags: linux, proxy, tunnel, http

On windows I used Bitvise Tunnelier, which is a neat free app capable of setting up a secured tunnel through http/https proxy.

On linux the only thing I found was corkscrew+ssh, which in terms of functionality a bit behind of Bitvise tunnelier imho.

The main problem is connection speed and handling of disconnects - with corkscrew it takes around a minute to just connect to the host, while it is almost instant with Bitvise.

Also, I couldn't find how to set it up to reconnect automatically while Bitvise does that by default.

So I guess I am looking for something similar to Bitvise only for Linux.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ssh takes a minute to connect, you probably have a problem with your ssh configuration. It could be reverse dns lookups are borked, or something else. Run sshd with -v option as well as ssh with -v and you should get a better idea of why it's taking so long.

Note that even if you don't have admin access to restart sshd on the server, you can still run your own instance of sshd on a different port with the -v option and ssh -v to that port instead of the default port 22.

That being said, if you don't want to use ssh to tunnel, you could use stunnel. It uses SSL instead of SSH to encrypt the sessions.

Comment: it's not ssh which takes long, it is actually corkscrew's part. If I launch it on its own, it is a fair bit of waiting there.

Comment: Why is stunnel better than ssh? Does it have server-side port forwarding?

Comment: I'm not saying stunnel is better; I'm just throwing it out as an alternative. But since it seems you need to go through a http proxy, stunnel is probably not what you want.